# Cannot run installed tool in Dockerfile even though its there

Tags: docker, rust-diesel

I installed [diesel-cli](https://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started) in a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:latest
ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"
RUN apk update
RUN apk add postgresql curl gcc musl-dev libpq-dev bash
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y
WORKDIR /app

RUN cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
CMD [ "docker/entrypoint.sh"]
```

That works fine. The `entrypoint.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"

ls /root/.cargo/bin/diesel
bash -c "/root/.cargo/bin/diesel setup"
```

The strange this is that the `ls` shows that the `diesel` binary is there. But when running the docker container it still says:

```
bash: line 1: /root/.cargo/bin/diesel: No such file or directory
```

I also tried calling `diesel` right from the `Dockerfile` with the same result.

Why can't I run `diesel` this way?

Comment: could be that its because of alpine. Those kinds of errors sometimes occur when using alpine due to incompatible or broken c dependencies. Can you try it with a different distro once?

Comment: How bizzare! Using `debian:buster` as base image resolved the problem. That is really confusing. Anyways, thanks a lot!

Comment: it's not that bizarre, if you consider that alpine is based on a different kind of c. It's build against musl, afaik.

Comment: 'Bizarre' was bad wording. 'Surprising' would have been a better choice, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comment by `The Fool`!

Using a different base image resolves the problem:

```
FROM debian:bullseye-slim
ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"
RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install postgresql curl gcc libpq-dev bash -y
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y

WORKDIR /app

# This may take a minute
RUN cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres

COPY . .
# provision the database
EXPOSE 8000
CMD [ "docker/entrypoint.sh"]
```